# Як перекласти «command-line shell»

Tags: переклад, from-english

Не можу правильно підібрати порядок слів і відмінки для перекладу *command-line shell*. Може *командно-рядкова оболонка*? Але звучить трошки незграбно.

Наведу переклад початку відповідної статті з англомовної Вікіпедії:

> **Оболонка** це інтерфейс користувач для доступу до служб операційної системи. Загалом, оболонки операційної системи використовують або інтерфейс з *командним рядом*, або *графічний інтерфейс*, залежно від ролі комп'ютера і конкретних операцій. Цю сутність називають оболонкою, бо це зовнішній шар навколо ядра операційної системи.

Тобто, це оболонка ядра ОС, а не командного рядка.

Comment: Якщо писати так, то, я думаю, писалося б «команднорядкова» (без «-»).

Comment: Хоча чомусь мені здається, що на практиці це частіше буде «командного рядка» (але поки не шукав приклади).

Comment: Дослівно так: "Оболонка командного рядка". Слово shell потрібно ставити на початку для перекладу. Не знаходжу підтвердження моїм словам.

Comment: Враховуючи вточнене запитання: ну тоді, мабуть, «оболонка з інтерфейсом командного рядка». Так, довга фраза. Але часто її використовувати, мабуть, не доведеться — просто «оболонка» (у кожній ОС зрозуміло, яка найуживаніша оболонка, непотрібно кожного разу вточнювати «з інтерфейсом командного рядка» чи «з графічним інтерфесом»; і англійською я теж «command-line shell» не часто бачу, частіше просто «shell»).

Comment: @Sasha якщо ви напишите обґрунтування своєму твердженню про без дефіса як відповідь, то я її прийму. Ваш варіант теж туди можна додати.

Comment: Зустрічав тільки варіант "оболонка командного рядка", але варіант команднорядкова по-моєму правильніше.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Виходячи з пояснення наведеного в запитанні вважаю найкращим варіантом **команднорядкова оболонка**.

Також доречним може бути варіант, який був у відповіді AndriyIvanchenko до редагування - **текстова оболонка**.

Answer (score 1):

**Командний рядок**

або

**Оболонка командного рядка**

Щоб зрозуміти як саме перекласти словосполучення, треба знати в якому контексті воно використовується.

**Командний рядок** («command-line shell» або «command shell») - це інтерфейс для введення текстових команд компьютеру. Стандартним інтерфейсом командного рядка Windows є **cmd**, для Mac OS - це **Terminal**.

**cmd.exe** складається з двох частин: спочатку з'являється вікно для роботи з текстовою консоллю, а після введення команди з клавіатури її обробляє інтерпретатор командного рядка. Icнують **покращені оболонки командного рядка**, наприклад, Windows PowerShell, Console2, rxvt, cygwin, TakeCommand, а також програмне забезпечення із доступом до командного рядка Windows, наприклад, Total Commander.

Давайте уточнимо кілька термінів.

**Shell** - це оболонка ядра операційної системи Unix, для Windows - це Windows Shell.

**Консоль** - це система в цілому. Це і командний рядок, і вихід з попередніх команд.

**Командний рядок** - це фактичний рядок у консолі, де ви вводите свою команду.

**Terminal** або **cmd** - це власне інтерфейс до консолі. Програма, яку ми використовуємо для взаємодії з консоллю, насправді є «емулятором терміналу», який надає нам досвід введення команд, як у старому терміналі Unix, коли графічних інтерфейсів ще не існувало, тобто лише відтворює його вигляд у сучасній графічній операційній системі, але фактично є програмою-обгорткою, отже **оболонкою командного рядка**.

Comment: Дякую. Але який це має стосунок до запитання? Автор же питає про те, як краще передати «command-line shell» українською, а не про те, що воно таке.

Comment: Хотілось би почути ваші аргуєменти на користь цього варіанту. У запитанні ви можете знайти аргумент проти.

Comment: Щоб зрозуміти як саме перекласти словосполучення, треба знати в якому контексті воно використовується і розумітися на архітектурі ОС. Взагалі «command-line shell» або «command shell» має тотожнє значення, але, наприклад, в браузері Firefox також можна користуватися консоллю, але оболонка командного рядка там відсутня. http://doctus-stilus.narod.ru/cons.html

Comment: Це не є відповіддю.

Answer (score 1):

> A [command line interface](https://techterms.com/definition/command_line_interface) (or CLI) is a text-based interface used for
>   entering commands.

Сполучення (сполука, сполучник) за допомогою наказового рядка - це текстове сполучення, що використовується для введення наказів.

> a [shell](https://techterms.com/definition/shell) is a software program that interprets commands from the
>   user so that the operating system can understand them and perform the
>   appropriate functions

Оболонка - це прикладна програма яка перетворює накази від користувачів таким чином, щоб операційна система могла їх зрозуміти і виконувати відповідні функції.

Тобто «command-line shell» - це **оболонка зі сполученням за допомогою наказового рядку**, або коротше **оболонка з текстовим наказом**, або ще коротше **текстова оболонка**, якщо дуже хочеться пропустити вид тексту, який вказують.

Comment: А до чого тут «сполучення»?

Comment: Interface - The interface between two subjects or systems is the area in which they affect each other or have links with each other. Моє розуміння слова interface - є слово сполучення. Визначення збігається з усіма випадками використання слова інтерфейс в ІТ. Спробуєте довести зворотнє?

Comment: Можливо, хіба що _**точка** сполучення_ в широкому значенні, але, як на мене, аж ніяк не просто _сполучення_. Надто вже широкий у слова _сполучення_ набір значень, і перше, що спадає на думку при читанні _сполучення_, — це аж ніяк не _interface_. Але це моє інтуїтивне відчуття, яке я поки що ніяк обґрунтувати не можу, можу помилятися.

Answer (score -3):

Командна оболонка. Причому не це теж саме, що командний рядок. Командна оболонка може бути різною (bash, fish, zsh і т.п.)

Comment: Ласкаво просимо до сайту Ukrainian Language.SE! Наші критерії якості дещо відрізняються від того, що можна побачити на мовних форумах і блоґах. Необґрунтовані відповіді базуються лише на думці їхнього автора і тому викликають хвилю диспутів і заперечень. А якісні відповіді ґрунтуються на якісних джерелах: словниках, поважних сайтах тощо. Будь ласка, перегляньте сторінки [tour], [answer] а також [«Якими мають бути гарні відповіді»](http://meta.ukrainian.stackexchange.com/q/5/). Ви завжди можете виправити відповідь, зробивши її більш аргументованою. Для цього натисніть [edit].

Comment: Ви можете надати якісь аргументи щодо переваг цього варіанта (чи проти інших)?